# T-SQL Assigning a running count of days in-between product launches resetting to zero when a product launches

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I need to assign a count of the days that have elapsed in-between different product launches. This is an example of the data that I have:

```
SELECT '2016-01-01' TiD, 1 Launch, NULL DaysBetween
INTO #TestingData
UNION
SELECT '2016-01-02', 0, NULL DaysBetween
UNION
SELECT '2016-01-03', 0, NULL DaysBetween
UNION
SELECT '2016-01-04', 1, NULL DaysBetween
UNION
SELECT '2016-01-05', 0, NULL DaysBetween;
```

I attempted to use this query:

```
SELECT TiD
       , Launch
       , COUNT(1) OVER(PARTITION BY Launch ORDER BY TiD) DaysSinceLastLaunch
FROM #TestingData
ORDER BY TiD ASC
```

However it does not reset the count to zero. If I need my end result to look like this:

```
SELECT '2016-01-01' TiD, 1 Launch, 0 DaysBetween
INTO #CorrectData
UNION
SELECT '2016-01-02', 0, 1 DaysBetween
UNION
SELECT '2016-01-03', 0, 2 DaysBetween
UNION
SELECT '2016-01-04', 1, 0 DaysBetween
UNION
SELECT '2016-01-05', 0, 1 DaysBetween;
```

What do I need to do? Should I use a cursor?

Thanks

Comment: If you have an associated ID or name of the project that is launching, a window function partitioned on that value would work just fine.

Comment: Google "SQL Gaps and Islands Problem" for lots of examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a quick CTE that does the job. The difference between this and the other answer is in the first part of the CTE where it takes `TOP 1` as opposed to `Launch = 1`, which could return more than a single row. (Honestly I've not tested the other answer).

**Note:** this assumes you always have consecutive days, which your sample data indicates that you do.

```
SELECT '2016-01-01' TiD, 1 Launch, NULL DaysBetween
INTO #TestingData
UNION
SELECT '2016-01-02', 0, NULL DaysBetween
UNION
SELECT '2016-01-03', 0, NULL DaysBetween
UNION
SELECT '2016-01-04', 1, NULL DaysBetween
UNION
SELECT '2016-01-05', 0, NULL DaysBetween

;WITH    cte
          AS ( SELECT TOP 1
                        TiD ,
                        Launch ,
                        0 AS DaysBetween
               FROM     #TestingData
               ORDER BY TiD
               UNION    ALL
               SELECT   t1.TiD ,
                        t1.Launch ,
                        CASE WHEN t1.Launch = 1 THEN 0
                             ELSE cte.DaysBetween + 1
                        END AS Launch
               FROM     #TestingData t1
                        INNER JOIN cte ON t1.TiD = DATEADD(DAY, 1, cte.TiD)
             )
    SELECT  *
    FROM    cte

DROP TABLE #TestingData
```

**Output:**

```
TiD         Launch  DaysBetween
2016-01-01  1       0
2016-01-02  0       1
2016-01-03  0       2
2016-01-04  1       0
2016-01-05  0       1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
WITH REC_CTE (tid,launch,Daysbetween)
    AS (
        -- Anchor definition
       SELECT  tid,
               launch,
               0 as Daysbetween
       FROM #tmp
       WHERE launch = 1
         -- Recursive definition
        UNION ALL
        SELECT son.tid,
               son.launch,
               father.Daysbetween + 1
        FROM #tmp son INNER JOIN
             REC_CTE father
        on son.tid = dateadd(dd,1,father.tid)
        WHERE son.launch = 0
    )

 SELECT * from REC_CTE order by tid asc
```

you can use a recursive CTE to do the job for you. On every iteration you will had +1 for each day from the last launch.

I can provide a sqlfiddle if you cant get it working, just let me know